# problem with apacite "while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, errors, apa-style

there's an error message in my file which i do not understand.

I'm using TeXnicCenter and JabRef/bibtex with the apacite-package.

I get an pdf but there is a space line in between the bibliography. I doublechecked the JabRef-File, especially for the entries below and above the space line but did not identify any mistake.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}%{hyphsubst}
\usepackage{ifpdf} %zur Fehlerbehebung, wenn kein .pdf produziert wird (hier vorsorglich)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%stellt sicher, dass auch Umlaute dargestellt werden können
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}%[ansinew]für eurozeichen
\usepackage{textcomp} %zur Behebung weiterer Umlautfehler
\usepackage{lmodern}% für weniger pixelige Schrift
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} %Löschen der Vorbelegung
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}} %Ausgabe des Inhalts aus leftmark rechts im Kopf
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}} %Ausgabe des Inhalts aus rightmark links im Kopf
\addtolength{\headwidth}{-0.4\marginparwidth} %%% verschiebt header manuell
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\usepackage{setspace}% erlaubt Befehle: singlespacing, onehalfspacing und doublespacing
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=3.5cm,top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}%für align-Umgebung, Formeln
\usepackage{ifthen}%schöne Tabellen mit toprule
\usepackage{booktabs}%schöne Tabellen für toprule etc
\usepackage{apacite}%Zitate im APA Style; mit [apaciteclassic] geht citeA-nicht
\makeindex
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} %setzt den Wert des Längenbefehls auf den angegebenen Betrag
\newcounter{roemisch}

%%*************** ENDE PRÄAMBEL*****************

\begin{document}
\normalsize
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\pagenumbering{roman} %Römische Seitennummerierung {roman}kleine Ziffern {Roman} große


%%********* INHALTSVERZEICHNIS  **************
\tableofcontents %Inhaltsverzeichnis
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}

\setcounter{roemisch}{\value{page}} \addtocounter{roemisch}{1} 



\include{Dok1} 


\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{\theroemisch}
\bibliography{Referenzen/Database} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. This is a template you got from someone, right? [Wegschmeißen](http://niederberger.com.de/latex-vorlagen). The problem seems to be with entries in the bib-file, which we don't have. I don't know what you mean by *space line*, maybe post to the german forum [goLaTeX](http://golatex.de/). A discussion forum is more helpful for general questions.

Comment: Thanks! No, its my own - i used it for my diploma thesis and now, several years later I used it as starting point for my phd. I tried to shorten it to get sth like a "minimal sample"... Space line is an empty (i. e. without text) line, do not know if it is the right word (german: Leerzeile).

Comment: The format of my phd will basicly be the same and it was a big thing to get all those packages for the tabulars and so on  i need that it finally worked out. But I got yout point and promise to give it a thought.

Comment: That is a very very strange translation into the english language. I have to say, *google translate* did not help here, but the first hit google gave me for  translate leerzeile` was correct: blank line or empty line.